# reading image from src/assets folder at runtime using props in React

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to display image randomly in React.
Images are placed inside src/assets folder.

I have to display them using props.

Row.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import {View, Text } from 'react-native';
const Row = (props) => (
   
    <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
       <img src={require(props.value)}> //Error: Cannot find module '../assets/icondelivery.PNG'
      
       </img>
       <Text>{props.value}</Text>
  </View>
)

export default Row
```

props.value contains : ../assets/icondelivery.PNG

Hierarchy is : src/assets/icondelivery.PNG

**Note**: If I pass <img src={require('../assets/icondelivery.PNG')}>  , it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put assets folder in public folder. Change path from ../assets/icondelivery.PNG  to ./assets/icondelivery.PNG
Use this code:

```
import React from 'react'
import {View, Text } from 'react-native';
const Row = (props) => (
  <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
    <img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + props.value}/>
    <Text>{props.value }</Text> 
  </View>
)

export default Row
```

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic image sources that are known then you can use `require()` in your definitions instead of within the img src itself.

For example

```
<Row value={require('../assets/icondelivery.PNG')} />
```

Then in the component:

```
<img src={props.value}>
```

If you have a structure containing the images like an array you could put `require()` there:

```
const images = [
    { name: 'delivery', src: requiure('../assets/icondelivery.PNG')}
    ...
    ...
]
```